# Directx: Obj file parsing to Index Buffer

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine, indices, .obj

I'm having trouble getting an index buffer to display some imported .obj correctly.
It's been taken into consideration coordinate system orientation. (The obj loader was hard coded)  can print out the indices fine, so it correctly fills a `DWORD` array to be read in and set:

```
vector < vector <float> > index;
index = GetObjData(FilePath, VERTEXINDEXLIST);
for (int n=0; n<index.size(); n++){
    m=m+index[n].size();
}
```

...

```
DWORD *IndexBuffer = new DWORD[m];
```

...

```
iBufferDescription.Usage                   =D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
iBufferDescription.ByteWidth               =sizeof(DWORD)*m;
iBufferDescription.BindFlags               =D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
iBufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags          =0;
iBufferDescription.MiscFlags               =0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iSRData;
iSRData.pSysMem=IndexBuffer;

Device->CreateBuffer(&iBufferDescription, &iSRData, &D3DIndexBuffer);
DeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(D3DIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
```

Here's a Maya generated .obj:

```
# This file uses centimeters as units for non-parametric coordinates.

mtllib tbox.mtl
g default
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.000000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.000000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.000000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
s 1
g pPlane1
usemtl initialShadingGroup
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 3/3/3 2/2/2 4/4/4
```

A 2D square with 4 vertices.Passed in through the function, `DWORD IndexBuffer`'s contents read:

```
2
1
0
3
1
2
```

(-1 from all indices, to conform to DirectX)
I will also add that some other things were set too, such as the `ID3D11RasterizerState`.

```
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC DrawStyleState;
DrawStyleState.AntialiasedLineEnable=true;
DrawStyleState.CullMode=D3D11_CULL_NONE;
DrawStyleState.DepthBias=0;
DrawStyleState.FillMode=D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
DrawStyleState.DepthClipEnable=true;
DrawStyleState.MultisampleEnable=true;
DrawStyleState.FrontCounterClockwise=false;
DrawStyleState.ScissorEnable=false;

ID3D11RasterizerState *DS_State;
Device->CreateRasterizerState(&DrawStyleState, &DS_State);
DeviceContext->RSSetState(DS_State);
```

Finally the render function is pretty standard:

```
void Render(){
float ColorBlue[] = {0.3f,0.3f,1.0f,1.0f};
DeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTargetView,ColorBlue);
    UINT stride=sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT Offset=0;
    DeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&D3DBuffer,&stride,&Offset);
    DeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);    
    DeviceContext->DrawIndexed(IndSz,0,0);
Swapchain->Present(0,0);

}
```

IndSz is a global, for the index size. Which is correct:
I created a debugger for it, giving feedback:

```
4 vertices
6 index array size //element size = IndSz 
Index 0: 2
Index 1: 1
Index 2: 0
Index 3: 3
Index 4: 1
Index 5: 2
```

The above gets parsed into 1 triangle.

```
|\
| \
|  \ 
|   \
------
```

I've concluded it might be another issue other than what I can conceive of. I've checked for culling issues, ordering, data type funniness, memory size craziness and it seems close to a rewrite now. Help!

Comment: I did notice that changing `DWORD *IndexBuffer` to UINT[] changed the model. As did changing `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` to `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT`. Kick me if I'm wrong, but a DWORD array should be compatible with `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT`? edit: I should add that I'm on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DWORD` will not change with the word size of your CPU, as funny as this sounds. `DWORD` is ***always*** 32-bit no matter the host CPU on Windows, it is effectively Microsoft's `uint32_t`. `UINT`, on the other hand, is very vague and likely to change with CPU word size. By the way, the appropriate data type to pair with `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT` is actually `WORD` (16-bit).

However, your actual issue here appears to be your use of `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP`. The imported model you showed consists of two faces, six vertices in a triangle strip is going to produce four faces.

You want `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST` if these 6 indices are supposed to produce exactly 2 triangles.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll hop back into code, will implement this and get back to you!

Comment: There lies a second question. This worked for the posted model file, if I switch the source file to a triangulated 3D cube, the vertices draw funny again. Is it necessary to define the world matrix or depth buffer to draw [a 2D, screen-space version] of a 3D mesh? It's my understanding it will just display a 2D version. (I'm experimenting)

Comment: ...or maybe, I'm looking at some z-intercept+; camera clipping... !

Comment: How exactly are you generating this screen-space version of your mesh? You would have to transform the vertices into clip-space by multiplying them by Model * View * Projection and then handle the viewport mapping manually; the process D3D uses. Even then, screen-space is actually a 3D coordinate space, it still has a Z value (though it is in the range [0,1]) which is necessary to implement depth buffering. So if I understand you correctly, yes - you still need a depth buffer to properly eliminate hidden surfaces.

Comment: GREAT! As a test for rendering 3D obj in 2D space, I set `DrawStyleState.DepthClipEnable` to `false` (for rasterizer description) and the whole 3D object was drawn with no clipping! (Which was a second issue occurring while trying to draw 3D objects with the correct index ordering) Problem solved!

Comment: Ah, I see. Actually that state only affects whether the Z values are clipped. X and Y are always clipped, but Z can be skipped... doing so can do some really weird things to depth buffering (e.g. points beyond the far plane all generate the same depth and points nearer than the near plane also generate the same depth).

Comment: I just confused 2D with screen-space lingo, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does that mean geometry detail will max on the near and far plane? (Appear flat?)

Comment: Not really, it just means that if you have two objects farther away than the far plane, for instance, that they will generate the same depth value everywhere. This means that the polygon drawn first or last (depending on depth test) will be the one that shows up, no matter how much farther away it may be than any other polygon. There is a description of this [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Depth%20Clamping.html), although it is written for OpenGL (where this feature is called depth clamping) the diagram and description still apply.

Comment: I see, that can get difficult to spot - strange to debug... you saved so much time down the road.  Will be posting further discussion/ issues in future posts. Thanks for your time and expertise!